# What Ruby template parsers are there besides ERB and HAML?

Tags: ruby, templates

What (preferably stable releases) alternatives exist to ERB and HAML for creating a HTML template parser with Ruby?

I would really love something like Django templates implemented in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) is not simply a template parser, but a template engine on its own.

It provides custom methods and filters, and it's own [weird] syntax. Yeah, just like in Django templates.